# Bootstrap div order on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/db7umm1w/) here.

It's super simple, text next on left of image, at smaller size the image drops below the text because of the order of the html.

I would like the image above the text at small window sizes.

The only way I can see is to have an image above and below and then hide and show the one I want.

Is there a better way to do this so I'm not loading double the amount of images?

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row">        
        <div class="col-sm-6 mobile-only">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        </div>          
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p>
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
            </p>              
        </div> 
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        </div>
    </div>       
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using push/pull modifiers should get you the effect you're looking for:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
            <p>
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
            </p>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle example, text on left/image on right, smaller screen image on top, text on bottom http://jsfiddle.net/db7umm1w/1/

Answer (score 1):

For this type of requirement , 1st we need to design the mobile view through html and use `pull` and `push` classes for other screens

Try this:

```
<div class="container">

           <div class="row">


               <div class="col-sm-push-6 col-sm-6   ">
                   <p>
                       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. 
                   </p>

               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-pull-6 col-sm-6  mobile-only">
                   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">

               <div class="col-sm-6">
                   <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
               </div>

           </div>

       </div>
```

Comment: that won't put it at top

Comment: Here is a link to a fiddle using the above method http://jsfiddle.net/db7umm1w/1/

Comment: However, the order of the DOM needs to be updated. img container first, then the html